# Tableview - Title overlapping Detail (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

The image attached says it all. Is there any way to prevent the title from overlapping such as automatically moving to a second line whenever it reaches its limit? programatically/through interface builder.

P.S: im retrieving the names from firebase database. this is a voting page and title are the booth names

TableView Controller

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

var pitchData = [String]()
var myIndex = 0
class PitchTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Gotham Rounded", size: 19)!]
        ref = Database.database().reference() //set the firebase reference
        // Retrieve the post and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Afternoon13").queryOrdered(byChild: "BoothPosition").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            pitchData.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key


                pitchData.append(key)

            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return pitchData.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Gotham Rounded", size: 20)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Gotham Rounded", size: 20)
        cell.textLabel?.text = pitchData[indexPath.row]

        switch (pitchData[indexPath.row]) {
        case "ARC - attract, retain and cultivate":
            let returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "voting")
            if (returnValue == 1)
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Completed ✓"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            else {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Vote ᐳ"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
            }
        case "Anytime RCs":
            let returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "voting1")
            if (returnValue == 1)
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Completed ✓"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            else {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Vote ᐳ"
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
            }
```

[image]

Comment: In tableview you have taken label or textfield.?

Comment: How did you build this view, via storyboard or via xib?

Comment: oh sry guys, let me add my code

Comment: the cells/tableview are in dynamic so everything is done via xib/controller

Comment: @Kinja Have added the answer for you reference, Hope it helps you

Comment: @Kinja you set your "UILabel" property "numberOfLines" = 0 and add "UILabel "  Top , bottom , leading , trailing Constraints

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoLayout in UITableview with dynamic cell height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724732/autolayout-in-uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-height)

Comment: @Kinja, did you try with demo link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set lines to 0:

[image]

**You can set it directly from StoryBoard:**

or you can set Programmatically:

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Hope this Help.

### Edit : Demo of the TableView Constraints

I have taken two labels in the cell next to each other:

**This is my Output of TableView:**

[image]

**This is constraint of label First:**

[image]

**This is the Constraints of label 2:**

[image]

And yes it worked for me, The text is multi line with no text cutting, please double Check your constraints with this.

### Edit To see the Constraints

**Select the label and then Select the Show the Size Inspector:**

Scroll Down and you can see the given constraints.

[image]

### Edit 2

As per you description you have Auto resizing:

So you can use the following :

**For label One**

[image]

**For label second:**

[image]

Comment: must i apply this to the detail text label as well?

Comment: @Kinja yes every label in the table view cell. This will make the text in two lines

Comment: @Kinja Have you given the Top, Bottom , leading and Trailing Constraints to the label? This make the best effect

Comment: Also show me your current constraints, That will help me finding you issue

Comment: apparently the constraints for both my labels are locked. could u do it for yours?

Comment: @Kinja You can see the Edited answer with the Constraints explained. And working Output.

Comment: sorry but how do u even get to that constraint page? I'm relatively quite new to swift. apologies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169131/discussion-between-abhirajsinh-thakore-and-kinja).

Comment: @Kinja Edited the Answer for Auto resizing Have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using default `UITableViewCell`'s **textLabel**, this should fix everything :

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
```

Comment: must i apply this to the detail text label as well?

Comment: If you want multiple lines for detail text label as well, then **yes**.

Comment: if thats the case, the problem still occurs. my text label did not do a line break

Comment: How does it look now ?

Comment: Can I see your heightForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: i never implemented any heightforrowatindexpath

Comment: Try this in viewDidLoad : tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0 //use an appropriate estimate
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

You set your **UILabel** property **numberOfLines** = 0

[image]

2. set **UILabel** Top , bottom , leading , trailing **Constraints**.

[image]

3. add **UITableViewDelegate** method.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
   ```
4. also set your **vote Constraints** like this.

[image]

5. select your **vote UIButton** set **Constraints**

   1. step set  Top , bottom , leading , trailing and fix width.

[image]

2. step set vertically center Constraints

[image]

Comment: is there a step-by-step tutorial on how to do the constraints? I'm so sorry I'm relatively quite new to swift

Comment: @Kinja see update answer for set vote UIButton constraints step.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fmKVhS apparently its locked i can set it (even if i untick "Constraint to margins"

Comment: @Kinja something wrong it's working for me try to quit xcode and reopen again.where is your vote button?.

Comment: oh shit sorry dixit, i might have said wrongly, its not a button, just a text label that segues to the next page

Comment: @Kinja Yes set UILabel trailing Constraints greater than or equal from superView.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure three things:-

- Title label has bottom, top and leading constraint with cell content view as well as horizontal spacing with Vote >, and Vote > button has all constraint like top bottom leading and horizontal space with title.
- Title label has set numberOfLines = 0
- Set dynamic height of cell using UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRowAt

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt 
  indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }
  ```

Comment: how can i set my Vote > constraints?

Comment: @Kinja see my ans.

Comment: it is a button that segues to another page

Comment: Ok then whats problem.. set constraint top, bottom , leading to cell content view and horizontal spacing with Title Label

Comment: Also make sure you have set title label top, bottom and leading constraint to cell content view

Answer (score 0):

Let try with code

```
// in view did load:
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

// cell row at indexpath
let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
        var cell:UITableViewCell? =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1,
                                   reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        }

        // your customize font, color... here

        cell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;

        return cell!
```